# Reformat a data.table ("long" to "wide" reshape)

Tags: r, data.table

I have a current R data.table that looks like this (toy example)

```
ID     Call    Sample
ID1      AA       S1
ID2      AB       S1
ID3      AA       S1
ID1      AB       S2
ID2      AB       S2
ID3      AA       S2
```

I'd like to create a new table from this one that (1) Groups by Sample, (2) Rearranges the table structure.  Here's what I want the output to look like

```
Sample    ID1    ID2    ID3
  S1      AA     AB     AA
  S2      AB     AB     AA
```

I'm familiar with the super basics of dplyr and data.table, but can't seem to quite figure this out.  If possible, I'd like to use these along with base R functions to do this transformation.  However, I'm also willing to branch out to other packages if this can't be done with these.

Comment: This is a standard "long" to "wide" reshape. Have you searched through the questions and answers already posted?

Comment: I couldn't find anything with my search parameters, but that was because I didn't know what it was called.  I'll search around and mark this as duplicate if I find something.  Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at `?dcast`.

Comment: See also the [vignette on reshaping with `data.table`](https://rawgit.com/wiki/Rdatatable/data.table/vignettes/datatable-reshape.html)

Comment: Answer, using above suggestions: dcast(df, Sample ~ ID, value.var="Call")